# "Go to symbol in file" not working for PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, windows-10, symbols

For some reason, the "Go to symbol in file..." dialog for PHP only has an empty list. That dialog works fine for other languages, like JavaScript or TypeScript, but not PHP. I've set the PHP executable path but it didn't make a difference.

Any idea what to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

By and large it should be one of tow things:
1) Your php plugin are not installed, I guess this is "PHP IntelliSense" plugin function;
2) Another plugin you just installed broke the php plugin;

Have a look at the plugin tag at the left side of the window and checkout which plugin to install or disable to check why is it not working.

Cheers